# Storing an xmlhttp Response for further use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a React App. I have 2 `xmlhttprequest`s in the same component. I'm trying to store the `responseText` from `xhr1` into some random new variable so that I can display it or send it as data in `xhr2`. How can I store the content of `xhr1.responseText` into say, `var resp`? It's not ajax and I'm not using `onreadystatechange` function. Sorry if my question is wrong, but I'm still new to this. Thanks.

```js
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.open('POST', 'http://myserver/login');
xhr1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr1.onload = function() {
  console.log('Refresh Key : ' + xhr1.responseText);
};
xhr1.send(JSON.stringify({
  "idToken": id_token,
  "fcmID": ""
}));

var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.open('POST', 'http://myserver/getAccessToken');
xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr2.onload = function() {
  console.log('Access Token : ' + xhr2.responseText);
};
//The following line doesn't work as expected. 
xhr2.send(JSON.stringify({
  "refreshToken": xhr1.responseText
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Is there any way I can make the last line of the code work?

Comment: Hi. Can you add a [mcve] of your current code so we can understand the question a little better? Just edit the question and add the code underneath the description.

Comment: Even if you do store the response to a var, AJAX is Asynchronous, so the var could be the var value before the AJAX call, unless you're accessing it upon `xhr.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: @Andy, I've put up the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because it is asynchronous . That means sending the request (or rather receiving the response) is taken out of the normal execution flow.

**Solution** : To solve this you can restructure your code and use **callback** like below :

A callback is simply a function passed to another function. That other function can call the function passed whenever it is ready. In the context of an asynchronous process, the callback will be called whenever the asynchronous process(xhr1 request) is done. Usually, the result (xhr1 response) is passed to the callback.

In your code, you can make handleData accept a callback and use it as success callback.
Hope it solve your issue .

```
 function handleData(callback) {

  var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr1.open('POST', 'http://myserver/login');
  xhr1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr1.onload = function() {  // when the xhr1 request is loaded
  console.log('Refresh Key : ' + xhr1.responseText);
  callback(xhr1.responseText); // xh1 response sent via callback

    };

   xhr1.send(JSON.stringify({
  "idToken": id_token,
  "fcmID": ""
    }));

  }


  handleData(function (result) {
   // code that depends on result of Xhr1 request
   var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr2.open('POST', 'http://myserver/getAccessToken');
   xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   xhr2.onload = function() {
   console.log('Access Token : ' + xhr2.responseText);
     };

   xhr2.send(JSON.stringify({
   "refreshToken": result // result is xh1 response received via callback
    }))

});
```

**handleData** function now  accept an action to run when the AJAX completes successfully.
You can also extend xhr1.onload = function() further by checking if the response status is 200 (i,e create a fail handler )  and then act accordingly .